# syntax error, unexpected 'in' (T_STRING) Laravel 5

Tags: php, string, view, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Controller class for Authors

```
public $restful=true;
    public function index()
    {
        $author = Author::all();
        return \View::make('authors.index', ['authors' => $author]);
    }
```

Model class for authors

```
class Author extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'authors';
}
```

View file for Author

```
@extends('layouts.default')
    @section('content')
        <h1>THIS IS AUTHOR'S PAGE</h1>

        <ul>
            @foreach($authors in $author)
                <li>{{ $author->name }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endsection
```

Display page for authors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD><TITLE>Testing</TITLE></HEAD>
    <BODY>
        @yield('content')
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Error response that I'm getting.

```
FatalErrorException in 6d4e39a843ef4ce0421f063e7b907f68 line 5:
syntax error, unexpected 'in' (T_STRING)
```

I'm unable to know exactly where this error is coming from since it returns a string code that is I'm unable to interpret.What can i do . Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be `as` instead of `in` (`in` do not make sense in this order):

```
@foreach($authors as $author)
    <li>{{ $author->name }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should replace

```
@foreach($authors in $author)
```

with

```
@foreach($author as $authors)
```